# Have iPhone webpage URL open in specific view in application

Tags: iphone

I have an application that acts like an internet browser for one webpage. If the webpage is in one view, can I have it act so when a specific URL is selected that it will open the URL in a different view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  In your webViewController, implement this

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

Check to see if it's the url you're interested in, then create and push a view that displays the web page.

Oh, and return NO to prevent the load from occurring in this view.